# zsh: /usr/local/bin/pipenv: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: no such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, zsh, pipenv, pyenv

I recently switched from bash to zsh (MacOS). I haven't used pipenv since the switch. Now when I run any pipenv command I get the following error:

```sh
$ pipenv install
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pipenv: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: no such file or directory
```

I use pyenv for Python dependency management:

```sh
$ which python
/Users/ryan.payne/.pyenv/shims/python
```

My default python version is 3.7.3:

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.16
  3.6.8
* 3.7.3 (set by /Users/ryan.payne/.pyenv/version)
```

It seems like pipenv is not using my pyenv version of Python. How do I get pipenv working again?

Comment: "Bad interpreter" means exactly what it says. Check the first line of the script that fails for the "shebang" -- the specification of what interpreter is to be used to run that script. Make sure that shebang points to an interpreter that actually exists.

Comment: ...if you want it to traverse your PATH to find a copy of `python` to use (and thus, to use the same one `which` finds), then you need it to start with `#!/usr/bin/env python`; whereas right now it presumably starts with `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7`, which the error message indicates doesn't exist or is missing runtime dependencies..

Comment: You did not mention OS you're using. Is it MacOS?

Comment: @AlexYu yes, it is a MacOS. I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to uninstall anything. Simply change the interpreter at `/usr/local/bin` and have your current python path in pyenv handy:

`type python3`

**copy the path**

`vi /usr/local/bin/pipenv`

It will look something like this:

[image]

Once it's changed, you will probably have to download pipenv again. Don't worry, your env is fine.

`pip install pipenv`

Go play in your env

Comment: I had the same problem with `black` on mac after `brew upgrade`. The similar procedure worked for me. Thnx

Comment: Yo! There you go! This is one of the best answer I would consider!

Answer (score 9):

I had this same error with `awscli`. The solution was to install python@3.7 via homebrew and then `cp` that installation into the directory `awscli` expected.

```sh
brew install python@3.7
cp -r /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

Answer (score 4):

If you installed pipenv with [pipenv with pipx](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#isolated-installation-of-pipenv-with-pipx), then you can reinstall pipenv via `pipx reinstall pipenv` which should detect any top level changes in your python environment.

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal:

```
brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

After brew installation, sometimes it may not work.
Depending on whether you tried to install other python versions, the links might not be working any more, and therefore running the command

```
brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Might give an error as below

```
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists.
```

Try to remove the file 2to3

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'
```

and run the above code again
Alternatively, you can force the linkage

```
brew link --overwrite python@<version>
```

but you can first see the files that will be deleted by this forced linking using the command

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@<version>
```

I hope this gives more light

Comment: I had python3 already installed so I just ran this command and it worked : cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python